# Can't access attribute with jQuery without appending the element to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone explain why this doesn't change the audio file `src` attribute, I would think it would?

```
var correctAudio = document.createElement('audio');
correctAudio.setAttribute('id', 'correctAudio');
correctAudio.setAttribute('src', 'sfx/correct/3.mp3');

function playCorrect(){
  var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
  num = num.toString();
  $('#correctAudio').attr('src','sfx/correct/'+num+'.mp3');
  correctAudio.play();
}
playCorrect();
```

It only works if I call `document.body.appendChild(correctAudio);`

Seems as if jQuery can only access the element if it is appended to the page - is this correct or is this a jQuery bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct behaviour. jQuery searches the document for a matching element, the element is not part of the document.

You can just wrap the existing reference to the DOM object using jQuery (rather then searching the document for a new reference to wrap):

```
 $(correctAudio)
```

… but you might find you still can't play it when it isn't part of the document.

Comment: Thanks, yep @Alvaro, that is right, you were close :-)

Comment: Odd that this answer works without adding the element to the document.

Comment: Must be because I am referencing the variable instance instead of the `id` of the element.

Comment: @whodeee — That's what the second paragraph of the answer says ;)

Comment: @Alvaro - you don't need the `$('body').append(correctAudio);` in that fiddle, works without it

Comment: @whodeee yeah, I just added in case he wants to inspect the DOM to verify it.